# How to map over inner keys of nested Associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, map, associations

Considering an association:

```
<|"a" -> <|aa-> "asc", bb-> "asd", cc-> 0, ImageType -> "asd", dd-> "asd"|>|>
```

How can I make the inner **keys** strings?

```
  <|"a" -> <|"aa"-> "asc", "bb"-> "asd", "cc"-> 0, "ImageType" -> "asd", "dd"-> "asd"|>|>
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
assoc= <|"a" -> <| aa-> "asc", bb->"asd", cc->0, ImageType->"asd", dd-> "asd"|>|>;
KeyMap[ToString]/@assoc
(* <|"a" -> <|"aa" -> "asc", "bb" -> "asd", "cc" -> 0, 
   "ImageType" -> "asd", "dd" -> "asd"|>|> *)
```

**Update:**

> but what if I have n levels?

I hope there is a better/cleaner way to deal with nested associations than the following:

```
assoc2= <| a-> <| aa-> "asc", bb->"asd", cc->0, ImageType->"asd", 
          dd-> <|dd1->"asd", dd2->"asd2"|>|>|>;

Replace[assoc2/. Association->foo, Rule[a_,b_]:>Rule[ToString[a],b],
        {0,Infinity}]/. foo->Association
(* <|"a" -> <|"aa" -> "asc", "bb" -> "asd", "cc" -> 0, 
   "ImageType" -> "asd", 
   "dd" -> <|"dd1" -> "asd", "dd2" -> "asd2"|>|>|> *)
```

Comment: This works for 2nd level only.

Comment: @SuTron, right; but isn't that your question (_How can I make the **inner** keys strings?_)

Comment: Yes, but what if I have n levels?

Comment: @SuTron, please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, not any of the association `*Map` (`KeyMap`, `AssociationMap`, `KeyValueMap`) functions accept a third argument for level specification. One can use `Replace` but with an extra `Evaluate`, as the replacement does not evaluate the `KeyMap` function:

```
ass = <|a -> <|aa -> "aa", ab -> <|ab1 -> "x", ab2 -> "y"|>|>|>;

Replace[ass, a_Association :> (Evaluate /@ KeyMap[ToString, a]), {0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"aa" -> "aa", "ab" -> <|"ab1" -> "x", "ab2" -> "y"|>|>|>
> ```

Without the forced evaluation, `ToString` is applied but not evaluated:

```
Replace[ass, a_Association :> KeyMap[ToString, a], {0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
>  <|"a" -> KeyMap[ToString, <|aa -> "aa", 
>          ab -> KeyMap[ToString, <|ab1 -> "x", ab2 -> "y"|>]|>]|>
> ```

(version 10.1, Win7 64)

Comment: I am not finding the Evaluate necessary; which version are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I consistently get the unevaluated result; could this be a bug? Or am I overlooking something about the internals of associations?

Comment: Probably just a change in evaluation; associations and datasets are still in flux it seems.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard BTW, do you have any idea why these functions are not applicable at different levels? `Association` is not meant to be a single-level vector, even the documentation has many nested examples, so I wonder.

Comment: My first guess is that it simply hasn't been implemented yet.  However I am curious: which parts of the documentation have *nested* associations rather than simply lists of associations?  I cannot at the moment recall examples of the former, but I also did not search.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Look around `Dataset`, under [**Applications > Associations of Associations**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0rs3seh0m-ctz8rn), e.g. `ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]`.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about that one.  Nevertheless it is with in a `Dataset` which has its own (somewhat nascent) mechanism for manipulation.  Are there any other examples?  I ask not because I think this *shouldn't* be handled, as I really think it should, but just for reference.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You might be right: while there are some examples (like [Associations as keys](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bim351e-6cjy24)), now that I scanned the docs I do have the feeling that an association is meant to be (used mainly as...) one-dimensional. And of course, there is [this](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bim351e-h8pcmy), which might indicate that the 1D-approach is intentional. But on the other hand, labeled data is [automatically used by charting functions](http://wolfram.com/xid/0tqlefhuksgd63-3hzlhk) as labels/legend...

Answer (score 2):

A derivative of István's answer:

```
asc = <|"a" -> <|aa -> "asc" + "zzz", bb -> "asd", cc -> 0, ImageType -> "asd", 
     dd -> "asd"|>|>;
AssociateTo[asc, "foo" -> asc];

fn[a_Association] := KeyMap[ToString, a]
fn[else_] := else

fn //@ asc // InputForm
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"aa" -> "asc" + "zzz", "bb" -> "asd", "cc" -> 0,
>    "ImageType" -> "asd", "dd" -> "asd"|>, 
>  "foo" -> <|"a" -> <|"aa" -> "asc" + "zzz", "bb" -> "asd",
>     "cc" -> 0, "ImageType" -> "asd", "dd" -> "asd"|>|>|>
> ```