# How to update values of nested association using AssociateTo?

Tags: expression-manipulation, associations

Saying we have an association:

```
asc = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>|>;
```

I want to updated values of `"A"`. I have tried doing:

```
AssociateTo[
  asc, 
  asc["A"][#] -> If[asc["A"][#] === 1, 0 , asc["A"][#]] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

> `<|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3|>`

But this just adds valuesst to the association instead of adding to `"A"`

How can I update the values in `"A"` using `AssociateTo`?

Comment: Closely related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/changing-values-in-an-association-using-map)

Comment: Possibly related? [(79686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79686/121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came up with a solution:

```
In[1]:= asc = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>|>;
Module[{tmp = asc["A"]},
 AssociateTo[tmp, # -> tmp[#] + 1 & /@ {"a"}];
 AssociateTo[asc, "A" -> tmp]
 ]

Out[2]= <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>|>
```

Comment: Why do you have to use `AssocTo`? It is a very poor tool for solving your problem. The simple expression `asc["A", "a"] = asc["A", "a"] + 1;` is much better.

Comment: The question asks how to do that using AssociateTo[]. For complicated and nested associations it's a better fit to apply changes, when you need to do additional checks on keys.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility would be the simple

`asc["A"]["a"] = 99;`

[image]

As @m_goldberg commented this can be shortened to

```
asc["A", "a"] = 99;
```

To change several keys:

```
asc[[1]][[2 ;; 3]] = 4
```

[image]

Comment: I need to that using AssociateTo

Comment: +1, but I would use `asc["A", "a"] = 99;`

Comment: Thanks @ Mr. Goldberg - that's a nice form - will update